# How to split parent path of a unc path by using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Here is a UNC path I've got.`\\sharespace\test1\10.0.1212.1`

Can I get its parent path`\\sharespace\test1\`?

Comment: Basic powershell questions are more likely to be tolerated and answered well on http://stackoverflow.com .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options. If you have access to the share then:

```
(Get-Item '\\sharespace\test1\10.0.1212.1').Parent.Fullname
```

If you do not have access to the share, you can go the more unpalatable route of manipulating the string in various ways. This is one:

```
$path = '\\sharespace\test1\10.0.1212.1'
[string]::Join('\', $path.Split('\')[0..$($path.Split('\').Length-2)])
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a cmdlet for this:

```
Split-Path \\sharespace\test1\10.0.1212.1
\\sharespace\test1
```

It doesn't include the trailing '\', but if you use Join-Path then PowerShell will take care of adding it if required anyway.

NOTE: Split-Path and Join-Path try to resolve the path on the local machine, so if the path has a drive letter (say, 'F:') that is not a valid drive on the local machine, these cmdlets will throw an error. With UNC paths like the above you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Fyi this doesn't work with UNC paths if you only have the host and ShareName `Split-Path "\\HostName.domain.com\ShareName"` but if you specify a folder under the share it works `Split-Path "\\HostName.domain.com\ShareName\test"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to parse the parent path out of the full UNC path.

```
$fullPath = "\\sharespace\test1\10.0.1212.1"
$parentPath = "\\" + [string]::join("\",$fullPath.Split("\")[2..3])
```